# Creating Excel files in SSIS based with a predefined format

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, reporting

I need to create a statistical report in Excel and wondering if I can use SSIS to read data from the database (calculate the aggregated numbers) and load them into an Excel file with a specific layout. From what I can see, in SSIS 2008 R2, we don't have control on the target excel file, cell by cell, or perhaps I missed something. Is there any way to achieve it through SSIS?

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just thought, but you could build this as a report in SSRS and have SSIS package run the report to Excel. http://msbimentalist.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/execute-ssrs-report-from-ssis-package/

Comment: Suggest you to look into [Building Excel Reports with PowerShell](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/01/30/building-excel-reports-with-powershell/).

Answer (score 4):

If your SSIS package runs with the appropriate file system permissions, you can create a template Excel file with the desired formatting and copy that file to a new one (using a file system or script task) where the data will be exported. If the sheet will contain a variable number of cells that must be formatted, you can use conditional formatting in the template and have Excel apply the format based on actual column values or a formatting flag, say in a hidden column, which could be populated from the data.

See [this article](http://brandietarvin.livejournal.com/28230.html) for an example of using a template. [This article](http://sqlsafety.blogspot.com/2009/12/updating-excel-spreadsheet.html) may also be helpful; it mentions an ingenious way to update specific cells.